# Unity3d Cloud builds failing with TextMesh errors

Tags: unity-game-engine

I recently setup cloud builds for a new project I created in Unity 2019.1.7. Both iOS and Android builds fail with the same exceptions.

> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TMPro' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>    error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TextMeshProUGUI' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TextMeshPro' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TextMeshProUGUI' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

And more of the same.

I can build Android locally without any issues.

Every script that references TextMesh Pro has a similar issue.

The builds are taking like 12 minutes before they fail so trying different things takes a very long time.

Comment: Make sure TextMesh libraries have been uploaded.

Comment: How would I go about updating the libraries? It was added automatically.

Comment: I mean upload (commit/push) not update, Which VCS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Bitbucket. I pushed all my changes so I don't have any file diffs.

Comment: Some files may be ignored, you may check again is the TextMesh Pro library and meta files in the server.

Comment: In the Packages folder, there are the TextMeshPro scripts but there is no .dll
Is the library built from the scripts? I tried adding the scripts from the Packages folder to the TextMesh Pro folder under Assets, but I get errors that pretty much all the scripts already exist.

Comment: In my project, there is only a manifest.json in the packages folder, and the library files is in the library folder, which is not used by the cloud build system. You may remove these files in packages folder and try again.

Comment: So the .gitignore I was using was an older one which excluded the .meta files. Once I updated to the latest .gitignore, I finally got a successful build. Thanks for your help!